# What does "GPU X does not have p2p access to GPU Y" mean?

Tags: gpu, caffe

If I have 4 gpu devices (0,1,2,3) and I'm running caffe, what does it mean if I see this:

[image]

Specifically what are the memory/run time implications if any?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have [SLI bridge](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/technology/sli/faq) between GPUs. Though you have 4 GPUs on your server, there is no direct connection between GPUs. It only makes communication slower, no any other effects.